# How much to cache?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm working on an iOS app and would like to cache some content in storage (I assume the best is `/Library/Caches`). In theory, the amount could add up to several gigabytes. The best would be for the operating system to handle how much can be cached and to delete the rest. But as I understand, iOS won't do that unless there is real pressure of resources. I would rather not get to that.

So how do I decide how much to cache?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no basic size to tell , but it depends on the current free space on the device ( which for sure will vary ) at this moment you need to wrap any write to a file inside a try catch as this may crash the app if it exceeds the current free space , also consider what you want temporary and put it inside tmp directory

Comment: I guess this is really the best, though that also means testing every so often.